# Have simpleid also provide the identifier

Tags: openid

I have a running simpleid installation, and I use my own homepage as the identifier. Now I want to add a user to simpleid who does not have a homepage or similar.

Does simpleid provide an identifier for its users automatically somehow?

E.g. after configuring `/var/lib/simpleid/foo.identity` I’d like to be able to use  `http://example.com/simpleid/foo` (or similar) as the identity for the user.

Answer (score 0):

A little later I found the answer in the [documentation](http://simpleid.koinic.net/documentation/getting-started/setting-identity/claim-your-identifier): simpleid provides a YADIS file. So with

```
$ cat /var/lib/simpleid/identities/foo.identity 
identity="https://example.com/simpleid/xrds/foo"
pass="deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"
```

I can use `https://example.com/simpleid/xrds/foo` as an OpenID without further setup.